# Direct email question from an AskDifferent user

Tags: support

So I just noticed an email that just arrived in my primary email.

It referred, specifically, to "Stack Exchange" of which I am not a member. So I assume it was referring to something on Ask Different or SuperUser. I searched on the title of the email ("Downgrading new 16” MacBook Pro: Catalina to Mojave") and didn't find an exact match.

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/354377/nigel-tungate) is the user (seemingly).

Looking at a few other people's profiles I see no email addresses listed. But I am wondering if Stack Exchange ever forwards email from users, displays a user's email address or did this guy just google me and find my email that way?

It's just a little freaky getting an email asking a Mac question directly from someone I don't know and as it *seemed* to come as a result of answers I have provided here I was hoping Meta might be the place to ask this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not provide your email address to users, either directly or through a redirection. SE can email you on the email address you provided based on inbox nofications which can include comments from users, but free-form emails are not made possible by SE.

This has happened to many of us on SE including me.
See prior discussion on Meta.SE: [Someone contacted me by email but my email is not public](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207872/someone-contacted-me-by-email-but-my-email-is-not-public)

Also, everyone here is a member of Stack Exchange!
https://stackexchange.com/users/493590/steve-chambers

Comment: Thx @GRG, I didn't *think so* but wanted some confirmation, and thx for the examples!